# Using Python to remove certain rows in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, datetime

Goal: To find the average elapsed time between GREEN and YELLOW statuses.  First I need to **remove all unnecessary rows.**  To find the elapsed time, I need the **first instance of GREEN followed by the first instance of YELLOW**, repeated over and over again.  Below is an excerpt of the 100,000+ rows.

In the example below, I would want to keep rows **1,2,5,6,9,13,14,15,16,21**

```
Row #   Serial Number   Time Stamp  Status <br>
1   1400004 3/10/14 11:52   GREEN <br>
2   1400004 3/15/14 11:45   YELLOW <br>
3   1400004 3/29/14 7:59    YELLOW <br>
4   1400004 4/16/14 15:59   YELLOW <br>
5   1400004 5/10/14 8:18    GREEN <br>
6   1400004 5/11/14 15:28   YELLOW <br>
7   1400004 5/23/14 14:10   YELLOW <br>
8   1400004 5/24/14 7:56    YELLOW <br>
9   1400004 5/26/14 7:59    GREEN <br>
10  1400004 5/28/14 8:26    GREEN <br>
11  1400004 5/30/14 7:28    GREEN <br>
12  1400004 6/1/14 16:56    GREEN <br>
13  1400004 6/13/14 17:29   YELLOW <br>
14  1400004 6/15/14 15:12   GREEN <br>
15  1400004 6/17/14 8:57    YELLOW <br>
16  1400007 1/3/14 11:55    GREEN <br>
17  1400007 1/4/14 15:31    GREEN <br>
18  1400007 1/15/14 14:44   GREEN <br>
19  1400007 1/17/14 5:37    GREEN <br>
20  1400007 1/18/14 5:35    GREEN <br>
21  1400007 1/18/14 18:32   YELLOW <br>
22  1400007 1/19/14 21:50   YELLOW <br>
```

Comment: what problem do you have ? Show your code and full error message. SO is not place to write your program.

Comment: And what is your expected output for the data you have given?

Comment: No time calculations needed.  I can handle that separately.  Just need to remove unnecessary rows.

Answer (score 2):

The following can be used to get just the lines you were looking for:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for k, g in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[4]):
        first_in_group = next(g)
        print first_in_group[0]     # show first column entry
```

This would display:

```
1
2
5
6
9
13
14
15
16
21
```

---

To expand on this, I suggest the following approach:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for k1, g1 in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[1]):   # group by serial number
        last = None
        entries = []
        for k, g in groupby(g1, lambda x: x[4]):    # group by status
            first = next(g)
            start = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(first[2], first[3]), '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

            if last:
                entries.append((first[0], k, start - last))
                print '{:4} {:7} {:>20}'.format(first[0], k, start - last)

            last = start

        average_seconds = sum((t[2] for t in entries), timedelta()).total_seconds() / float(len(entries))
        print "Entries: {} Average mins: {}".format(len(entries), average_seconds / 60)
        print
```

This will display the following output for your given data:

```
2    YELLOW      4 days, 23:53:00
5    GREEN      55 days, 20:33:00
6    YELLOW        1 day, 7:10:00
9    GREEN      14 days, 16:31:00
13   YELLOW      18 days, 9:30:00
14   GREEN        1 day, 21:43:00
15   YELLOW       1 day, 17:45:00
Entries: 7 Average mins: 20340.7142857

21   YELLOW      15 days, 6:37:00
Entries: 1 Average mins: 21997.0
```

One issue is that your timestamp resets for each new serial number, so if you calculate the difference you would get a very negative time. Also, it is not clear if your date and time are in one column or two? This script assumes two columns, e.g.

```
Row,#,Serial,Number,Time,Stamp,Status
1,1400004,3/10/14,11:52,GREEN
```